# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 1

Tags: php, javascript

No entiendo porque sucede este error de sintaxis:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 1

Cuando quiero parsear un json ya he revisado el código y todo parece estar bien.

```
function verificarPresupuesto(e){
    const valorPorcentaje = parseInt(e.target.value)
    console.log(valorPorcentaje)

    if(presupuesto.value != '' && typeof valorPorcentaje === 'number' && !isNaN(valorPorcentaje)) {
        $.get({
            url: `${URL_PRINCIPAL}/validarPresupuesto.php`,
            data: { valorPorcentaje, presupuesto_id: presupuesto.value},
            success: function (data) {
                // Covertimos el json a un arreglo plano de javascript
                const info = JSON.parse(data)

                valorCampaña.value = (info.total_presupuesto * valorPorcentaje) / 100;
                const superoPresupuesto = Number(info.presupuesto_restante) < Number(valorCampaña.value);
                validarSuperoPresupuesto(superoPresupuesto)

            },
          });
    } else {
        valorCampaña.value = 0;
        validarSuperoPresupuesto(false)
    }
}
```

Comment: Si te aparece ese mensaje, es por que la respuesta que viene de tu servidor no es un json, entonces lo primero que deberías hacer el verificar que salida te devuelve tu backend

Comment: Haz el console antes de hacer parseInt y verifica que estructura tiene